# Залил на гит, на другой файл html не переходит, как исправить?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

[image: Главная страница сайта]Вопрос такой, на локальном сервере все работает, залил на гит, на другой файл html не переходит, как исправить?

Часть кода шапки

```
<a href="/index.html"> Главная
<a href="/news.html"> Сеансы
<a href="/index.html#reviews"> Отзывы
<a href="/index.html#contacts"> Контакты
<a href="/new-format.html"> Новости
<a href="/index.html#about-us"> Обо мне
<a href="/blog.html"> Блог
```

[image: при переходе на Новости вылетает ошибка!]
[image: Вот так выглядит репозиторий]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: напиши код одной ссылки

Comment: попробуй ./blog.html

Comment: спасибо. сейчас попробую)

Comment: Бери от меня лайк

Comment: попробывал исправил. не работает(((

Comment: Я Тоже пользуюсь github pages там надо подождать или сделать заметное изменение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас файлы в одной папке находятся. Попробуйте убрать "/" в начале href.
Есть пример сайта, там такая же структура файлов и все работает:
https://github.com/Zhuchokk/zhuchokk.github.io/blob/main/index.html